# Part cannot be withdrawn if condition not fulfilled

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have three tables in MS Access 2010:

```
PART_ID SERVICE_DATE
  A1     06/01/2013
  B1     06/02/2013
  A1     07/04/2013

PART_ID DRAW_DATE  DRAW_TO
  A1    06/05/2013   501
  B1    07/12/2013   604

PART_ID RETURN_DATE RETURN_TO
  A1    07/03/2013    STORE
```

I've got the transaction history in form like this:

```
PART_ID SERVICE_DATE DRAW_DATE  DRAW_TO  RETURN_DATE RETURN_TO
  A1     06/01/2013  06/05/2013   501    07/03/2013    STORE
  A1     07/04/2013
  B1     06/02/2013  07/12/2013   604
```

There are few conditions:

1. Same part can be recycled in service, withdraw & return.
2. `SERVICE_DATE < DRAW_DATE < RETURN_DATE.`
3. A1 can be withdrawn since it has returned to Store and serviced.

Now, I want this:
B1 cannot be withdrawn. System will prompt `disallow` if user want to withdraw B1.

But I don't know how to start and what title to look for. Can somebody help in getting me the code or direct me to any related page? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you designed out a form for this?  Because it sounds like you know what you want to do, so you should try create a form first and then compare the values selected from your listbox, combobox, or subform and use those in an `IF` statement in your VBA editor.